# How to extract only specific string matching lines from a multiple lines standard input

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a standard input piped from another bash function output in the sample form:

```
fruit=apple
dog=doberman
car=bmw
flower=tulip
---
fruit=orange
dog=corgy
car=ford
flower=rose
---
```

...and so on repeated thousands of times...

From this multiple repeating piped standard output I want to extract only the values matching say fruit and car, like so:

```
apple
bmw
---
orange
ford
---
```

It would be even better if the sed/awk magic can output those in csv table-like format, like so:

```
apple,bmw
orange,ford
```

I have only basic knowledge in bash string input manipulation magic, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi there. What code have you tried? Do you have to use bash/awk/sed only?  Have you considered perl?

Answer (score 3):

No magic required - save the values in an array when they're seen in the input and print them when you hit a `---` line:

```
$ awk -F'=' -v OFS=',' '/---/{print v["fruit"], v["car"]} {v[$1]=$2}' file
apple,bmw
orange,ford
```

Comment: you're not resetting `v`, if a record is missing one of the keys it will repeat the previous value incorrectly.

Comment: @kvantour Correct and I'm also not accounting for any non-terminating  line that contains `---`, nor cases where the same key is duplicated in a record. I'm assuming if any of those can happen that the OP would show it in  her example.